# What is the lowest bound for this inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, reference-request

It is known that $(a+b)^2\le 2a^2+2b^2.$

I am wondering what is the lowest bound for this: assume that $k$ is a positive even integer, what is the smallest known $M$ for

$$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)^k\le M\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^k\right),$$
where we also assume that all $x$ are positive?

I know that one $M$ is $N^k$ by 
$$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)^k\le \left(N\max(x_i)\right)^k\le N^k\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^k\right).$$

But is there a smaller $M$?, what is the smallest $M$ we can choose? Is there some way that $M$ can be proportional to $N$?

Comment: Power-Mean Inquality gives us that $M = N^{k-1}$ is a better estimate, but I don't know whether it can be made better or not

Comment: If the $x_i$ are all equal, $N^k=MN$, so $M=N^{k-1}$ is the best possible.

Answer (score 0):

By the above discussion of
Chappers and Stefan4024, using Holder inequality, wo obtain
$$
\frac 1N\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\leq \left(\frac 1N\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i^k\right)^{\frac 1k}\cdot\left(\frac 1N\sum_{i=}^{N}1\right)^{\frac{k-1}{k}}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\right)^k\leq N^{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i^k,
$$
where the equality holds if and only if $x_i$ are all equal.